# How to align 2 fields into 1 row?

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm new to css. My jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/PAHdH/

```
<div>
    <label>Name: </label><p>John</p>
    <label>Age: </label><p>35</p>
    <label>Level: </label><p>60</p>
    <label>Score: </label><p>5000</p>
</div>

label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    color:black;
}

p {margin-bottom:2px; padding:0;}
```

​

I would like to change to

Name: John Age: 35

Level: 60 Score: 5000

It should be like a table with 4 columns.

Comment: Given your accepted answer, why not use a table instead? It makes semantic sense in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PAHdH/14/)***

Hi now your **markup is wrong** please change to your **markup html and css** write

**as like this**

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <p> <label>Name: </label>
       <span>John</span>
       <label>Age: </label><span>35</span></p>


    <p><label>Level: </label><span>60</span>
        <label>Score: </label><span>5000</span></p>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
label, span{
float:left;
    margin:1px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        width:150px;
    padding:2px;
}
p{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PAHdH/14/)***

Comment: I think the OP is not after this kind of formatting.  From his question it seems the first row should be: Name | John | Age | 35, second row Level | 60 | Score | 5000

Comment: Yes this is what i need except the background color :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using P, avoids the idea because it generates newline before and after the element.
I hope this could help.

```
<div> 
  <p>
    <label>Name: <span>John</span></label>
    <label>Age: <span>35</span></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Level: <span>60</span></label>
    <label>Score: <span>5000</span></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

I used P on where I need to create a new row, and changed your P to SPAN..
Here's the CSS

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    color:black;
    border:#000 1px solid;
}

span {margin-bottom:2px; padding:0; }
p { clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to modify your css, get rid of the <p>

Of course label should really connect to <input> element

```
<label for="name">John</label>
<span id="name">male<span>
<label for="age">Age</label>
<span id="age">35<span>

<br/>

<label for="level">Level</label>
<span id="level">100<span>
<label for="score">Score</label>
<span id="score">1000<span>
```

gives

John male Age 35
Level 100 Score 1000

as an after tought, if you really want to use <p> then use style

```
p { display: inline-block;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use in this way.

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    color:black;
}


span {margin-bottom:2px; padding:0;margin-left:10px;}


<div>
    <label>Name:<span>John</span><span>Age:</span><span>35</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, its questionable to associate `label` with something that isn't a form element. This may be more suited to a [definition list](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/dl). It may also to be semantically correct to use a table here as you have tabular data to display as a table.

**Definition List Example**

*HTML*

```
<dl>
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>Jon</dd>
    <dt>Age:</dt>
    <dd>35</dd>
    <dt>Level:</dt>
    <dd>10</dd>
    <dt>Score:</dt>
    <dd>100</dd>
</dl>
```

*CSS*

```
dl
{
    position:releative;
}


dd
{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

dt
{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwavM/

**Table Example**

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr> 
         <th>Name:</th>
         <td>John</td>
         <th>Age:</th>
         <td>35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
         <th>Level:</th>
         <td>100</td>
         <th>Score</th>
         <td>100</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```